# How to set mergefield to show long date format?

Tags: microsoft-word, date, mail-merge, german

How can I make Word 2012 display German date format in mail merge?

`{ DATE \a "dd.MM.yy" \ * MERGEFIELD }` returns `15.02.2012` for today, `15. Februar 2013` however is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Word 2010, the field code needs to be;

```
{DATE * MERGEFIELD \@ "d.MMMM.yyyy"}
```

I would imagine it will also work in your version.

Comment: This works, but outputs the english format, not the German month names. I get `February` instead of `Februar`. How to change that?

Comment: Word uses the regional settings are in your OS. So, you need to change it there.

Comment: No, thats not working. The same setting outputs different in different documents.

Comment: OK. Then check Word options to see if German is installed and set to default. If not, install it.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the entire field and click the Language button down the bottom left of the window (it should say English (US) for example). From the prompt choose German and press okay. Press F9 to update fields and the date should now be in German.